# How to show different strings in a Another Activity?

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I'm trying to display different texts for a textview according to the listview listitem click. For now Am creating Lot of new activities to achieve this task. Following Codes are one of that scenario. Is there any simple way to show the different texts in a Same Activity(BSC Activity). I dont want to create Post Activity. For an example If listview `position == 0` item clicked

> R.String.Bsc

have to display in bsc Activity. If `position == 1` clicked

> R.String.Post

Have to display in bsc activity.

ListView class

```
public class AHSMLS extends AppCompatActivity{

    ListView list;
    String[] itemname ={
            "Degree in Physiotherapy",
            "Post Graduate options"

    };

    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.mlsico,
            R.drawable.mls
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cp_listview_main_activity);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Physiotherapy");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.physiotherapy);

        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (position == 0) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Bsc.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }else if (position == 1){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Post.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Bsc activity

```
public class Bsc extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_multiple_text_view);

        TextView tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.durationtextView);
        tv3.setText("•\t 3 or 4 Year");

        TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.institutiontextView);
        tv4.setText(R.string.bsc);


    }
}
```

Post activity

```
public class Post extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_multiple_text_view);

            TextView tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.durationtextView);
            tv3.setText("•\t 3 or 4 Year");

            TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.institutiontextView);
            tv4.setText(R.string.Post);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Just get a `TextView` in your `cp_listview_main_activity` layout and change the text based on the position in your `ListView`.

Comment: i dont know how to achieve this.Can you explain with a sample code?

Comment: The question you asked is too broad. Please go through the android documentation first for some basic understanding on how activity, layout and listview interactions work.

Comment: ok. I have an idea can you give a sample code for that? If we get the selected items position to the Bsc activity from AHSMLS activity. can we set strings according to the position index in the bsc activity??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got your question correctly. Is this one You looking For? With this solution you dont need your post class. You can change your texts with the Bsc class.

ListView class

```
    public class AHSMLS extends AppCompatActivity{

        ListView list;
        String[] itemname ={
                "Degree in Physiotherapy",
                "Post Graduate options"

        };

        Integer[] imgid={
                R.drawable.mlsico,
                R.drawable.mls
        };
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.cp_listview_main_activity);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle("Physiotherapy");
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.physiotherapy);

            CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Bsc.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                //Add your data to bundle
                bundle.putInt("x", position);

                //Add the bundle to the intent
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Bsc activity

```
 public class Bsc extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv3;
    TextView tv4;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_multiple_text_view);

         tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.durationtextView);
         tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.institutiontextView);

        //Get the bundle
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        //Extract the data…
        int stuff = bundle.getInt("x");

        if(stuff == 0){

            tv3.setText("•\t 3 or 4 Year");
            tv4.setText(R.string.bsc);

    }else if(stuff == 1){

            tv3.setText("•\t 3 or 4 Year");
            tv4.setText(R.string.Post);
}

        }
    }
```

So you dont need Your Post activity Here. Good luck Bro!

Answer (score 0):

(sorry about the crappy formatting... still have never figured out how to preserve indentation when pasting code)

Anyhoo.... I think this is what Reaz Murshed is try to say:

```
public class AHSMLS extends AppCompatActivity{

// START NEW CODE
TextView tv3;
TextView tv4;
// END NEW CODE



ListView list;
String[] itemname ={
        "Degree in Physiotherapy",
        "Post Graduate options"

};

Integer[] imgid={
        R.drawable.mlsico,
        R.drawable.mls
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cp_listview_main_activity);


    // START NEW CODE
    tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.durationtextView);
    tv3.setText("•\t 3 or 4 Year");

    tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.institutiontextView);

    // END NEW CODE




    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Physiotherapy");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.physiotherapy);

    CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (position == 0) {

                // START NEW CODE
                tv4.setText(R.string.bsc);

            }else if (position == 1){

                tv4.setText(R.string.Post);
                // END NEW CODE

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Boober. But sorry you got the question wrongly.  I need to set those `tv4.setText(R.string.bsc);` in the Bsc activity. I dont want to create a Post activity. Is there anyway to show the `tv4.setText(R.string.bsc);` and `tv4.setText(R.string.Post);`. in the same Bsc activity?

Comment: Well I am just confused now.  Maybe rewrite your question more clearly and include the requirements.  You said "same activity" which is what this code does.

Comment: Soo.... if the requirements of your assignment are that you must start a new activity when the user makes a selection, then you could accomplish what you're trying to do either by using A) a static class or static variable to store their choice, or B) using an "intent extra" to send the choice to the new activity.

Comment: I only see -4.  Looks like someone else answered also maybe try that.